# How to manipulate the variable containing xml using xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have requirement with xsl variable containing xml.

```
<xsl:variable name="file" select="document('abc.xml')"/>
```

abc.xml is nothing but some sample xml `<a>1<b>2</b>3</a>`

Now I have to modify/add elements of the variable $file and assign the result to another variable..

My input will be

```
<Service name="CBI" detailedLog="false">
    <PolicyRules type="default">
        <EndPoints>
            <EndPoint source="Src" target="ET" serviceoperation="AV01">
                <Url>http://firstbackend.com</Url>
            </EndPoint>
            <EndPoint source="Src" target="ET" serviceoperation="PV01">
                <Url>http://secondbackend</Url>
            </EndPoint>
        </EndPoints>
    </PolicyRules>
</Service>
```

I have to fetch the  tags along with $file..I need the following output..

```
<a>1<b>2</b>
<Url>http://firstbackend.com</Url>
<Url>http://secondbackend</Url>
3</a>
```

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 1):

Store the main input document into a global variable e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>
```

then write a template for the element you want to transform e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="b | b/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$main-doc//Url"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="b/following-sibling::node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then apply the templates and store in a variable (if needed) e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="rtf1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$file/node()"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

then use that variable to output the result e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$rtf1"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The input for this xsl will not be <a>1<b>2</b>3</a>.It is something else which is entirely different..I have to access that variable and do the manipulation..

Comment: @ MArtin--How can I do template match="a" as in my input there will not be <a> tag..

Comment: @ Martin--
My input to the xsl will be <Service...> and <a...> is stored in file variable in the xsl..I want the output as mentioned above...

Comment: Martin : I deleted (or tried to?) my question cause it looks now it was not addressing the real problem, I answered too quickly I guess.  I have not time left for today, so I thought it was best to just delete it, but I felt I owned you an explanation since you commented it

Comment: @user1731504 : my solution might not have addressed your problem, good luck, peter

Comment: user1731504, you say the document you load with the `document` function contains an `a` element, so of course you can write a template for that, as I have shown, and that is then applied in `<xsl:variable name="rtf1"><xsl:apply-templates select="$file/node()"/></xsl:variable>`, as I have also shown.

Comment: The only thing missing: you could have mentioned RTF and `xxx:node-set()`

Comment: @ Dimitre Novatchev-- Could you please tell me in brief

Comment: user1731504, you don't need any `xxx:node-set` as far as you have described your requirements. Only if you wanted to use XPath on `$rtf1` or wanted to apply a further transformation step on the nodes in the result tree fragment `$rtf1` you would need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf1)//*" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>`. But as long as you don't have a result tree fragment (and your `$file` is not a result tree fragment, only `$rtf1` is but `copy-of` works fine with rtfs) you don't need such an extension function.